# Can I use bcrypt to compare passwords which are already hashed?

Tags: node.js, backend, bcrypt, login-page

I’m a newbie to nodejs and struggling with an issue regarding password hashing. I am recreating a website using ReactJS and using nodejs for the backend. There is a table in the database called userprofiles. It has email, hashed password, firstname, lastname etc. I am trying to create the login page as a start and I only need a login page not a register page, because I already have the user table from the previous database. I used bcrypt to compare the hashed password but those passwords not hashed by bcrypt because previous website was created using php since it used different method to hash the password. My question is can I use bcrypt.compare to compare my password when login?

Can I still use bcrypt? Please advise me on this matter, thanks.

Comment: you basically need to match the same method used to hash and compare, whatever that is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) is the `bcrypt.compare()` that you are using, then `bcrypt.compare()` does not compare two hashed passwords.

It compares a plain text password to a hashed password.  It uses the stored parameters (such as salt) that are in the hashed password in order to make a hash of the plain text password using the same salt so it can then compare the two hashes.

Since hashed passwords would typically only be created on your server, one can usually adapt your code to accommodate this.  The user doesn't know the salt used so they will submit a plain text password (usually protected in transport by https).

One possibility if you can't avoid comparing two bcrypt hashed passwords is to just directly compare the two hashes using something like [crypto.timingSafeEqual()](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#cryptotimingsafeequala-b).  The bcrypt has consists of an algorithm identifier, an iteration level, a salt and the hash.  Two identical original passwords should result in the same bcrypt hash value (same algorithm, same salt, same iteration level, same hash and thus same binary value).  But, I haven't tried that myself.

This is what a bcrypt hash value looks like:

```
Resultant hashes will be 60 characters long and they will include
the salt among other parameters, as follows:

$[algorithm]$[cost]$[salt][hash]

2 chars hash algorithm identifier prefix. "$2a$" or "$2b$" indicates BCrypt
Cost-factor (n). Represents the exponent used to determine how many iterations 2^n
16-byte (128-bit) salt, base64 encoded to 22 characters
24-byte (192-bit) hash, base64 encoded to 31 characters

$2b$10$nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veuK0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa
 |  |  |                     |
 |  |  |                     hash-value = K0kSxUFXfuaOKdOKf9xYT0KKIGSJwFa
 |  |  |
 |  |  salt = nOUIs5kJ7naTuTFkBy1veu
 |  |
 |  cost-factor => 10 = 2^10 rounds
 |
 hash-algorithm identifier => 2b = BCrypt
```

Comment: thanks so much for comment. Apologies if my post misled you. I have a users table with a hashed password column. It was hashed using php. 
I want to build a new login page using react and node. Since passwords are already hashed I only need to compare the hashed password with the password which user enter when he login. For that can I use bcrypt.compare(hashed password, req.body.password)?

Comment: @WathsalaHeenkende - The arguments are passed as `bcrypt.compare(myPlaintextPassword, hash, callback)`.  That should work fine for a login page.

Comment: @WathsalaHeenkende - If this answered your question, then you can indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points for following that procedure.

Comment: Thanks so much, I'll do it.